# how can i make complete data when using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

how can i make complete data when using NSURLConnection?

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
}
```

paste parts of NSData?
What should i do clearly i want to download a file from url address to my document directory and i want to know how many bytes has been downloaded to complete what is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a NSMutableData and append it when you receive the data.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data  {
    if (responseData == nil)  {
        responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    [responseData appendData:data];
}
```

Or

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data  {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}
```

Then deal with that data in `connectionDidFinishLoading`

Remember to release the data and connection once you finish it.

For more detail you may refer to this document: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

Comment: I updated my answer, responseData is an instance of NSMutableData